# Getting JSON From URLOpen

Tags: python, json

**I cannot consistently get JSON from a given url.** It works only about 60% of the time

```
jsonurl = urlopen('http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/hot.json?limit=16')
r_content = json.load(jsonurl)['data']['children']
```

The program crashes on the second line sometimes, because the info from the url is not retrieved properly for some reason

With some debugging, I found out that I was getting the following error from the first line:

```
<addinfourl at 4321460952 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x10185b050>>
```

**This error occurs about 40% of the time, the other 60% of the time, the code works perfectly. What am I doing wrong? How do I make the url opening more consistent?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually not an issue from the client side. Your code is consistent in behavior but the server response can vary.

I ran your code a few times and It does throw up certain issues:

```
>>> jsonurl = urlopen('http://www.reddit.com/r/funny/hot.json?limit=16')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Unknown
```

You have to handle cases where server response is anything but HTTP 200. You can wrap your code in a `try` / `except` block and you should pass `jsonurl` to json.loads() only when your request succeeds.

Also urlopen returns a file-like descriptor. Hence if you `print jsourl`, it simply provides `jsonurl.__repr__()` value. See below:

```
>>> jsonurl.__repr__()
'<addinfourl at 4393153672 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x105978450>>'
```

You have to look for the following::

```
>>> jsonurl.getcode()
200
>>>
```

and only if it 200, should you process the data obtained from the request.